# change product page information from tabs to one column

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, column, product-details

I am trying to change the way displaying the tabs in product page ( details, more information and reviews ).
I don not want it to be tabs I want it to display directly one after one: details then reviews then more information all showing on the same time not tabs.
I hope that I explained it correct
[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ? If yes, can you share it, and the problem you're having ?

Comment: no I could not found any related question about this and I did not found the file that I should modify

Answer (score 0):

You can review & override the following files, which are intended to display tabs in product page.

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml
```

You can remove tabs by remove or change **data item title** & **data item content** class, or you can change HTML structure as per your requirement.

Comment: can you share idea of the code to do what I want ?

Comment: Have you reviewed the mentioned file?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in @HarishKuril 's answer, the tabs and content are managed in the following file :

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml
```

You should copy it into your theme under the following path (replace **<vendor>** and **<theme>** with your theme path) :

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml
```

In this file, removing the `data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'` at the line 12 should be enough to prevent it from displaying tabs.

You might also have to add some CSS or modify some classes to improve how it will be displayed.